# How to find most frequent letter and number of occurrences from a text file?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, character

My Program needs to find a letter that has the most occurrences from a text file and then display the letter and the number of occurrences. Also the whole string from the text file has to be converted from lowercase to uppercase.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("letter_count.txt");
    string letter;

    char ch;
    char alphabet[26] = { 0 };
    int counts = 0;
    while (inputFile)
    {
        // Read file
        inputFile.get(ch); 
        if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            //Make all letters upper case    
            toupper(ch);

            //Counts number of occurrences for each letter
            if (ch >= 'A' || ch <= 'Z')
            {
                alphabet[counts++];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) //Displays number of occurrences for each         character A-Z
    {
        cout << alphabet[i] << endl;
    }

    inputFile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We can see your program, and the description of what your program has to do. What is your question?

Comment: `alphabet[counts++];` is certainly wrong. Don't you find it odd that you went to all that trouble to try and get something in `A..Z`,(you didn't, look closer) then never used it after that? And if you want to avoid the pitfall of non-contiguous character encoding (they still exist), you would want a map instead of an array for counting regardless.

Comment: I see your point somewhat but my professor requires that it be done as an array

Answer (score 3):

```
toupper(ch);
```

doesn't change the case of ch. The `toupper` function *returns* the upper case value so you need

```
ch = toupper(ch);
```

Next

```
alphabet[counts++];
```

is clearly wrong as it doesn't use the value of `ch`. You need a way to convert `ch` into an integer so that you can use that integer to index the `alphabet` array. I.e. you need to convert 'A' -> 0, 'B' -> 1, 'C' -> 2 etc. Making the almost certainly true assumption that you are using the ASCII character set, you can do that with a simple subtraction

```
ch - 'A'
```

Putting that together with the incrementing code you get

```
alphabet[ch - 'A']++;
```

Finally this is wrong

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) //Displays number of occurrences for each         character A-Z
{
    cout << alphabet[counts] << endl;
}
```

since your loop variable is `i` but for some reason you used `counts` inside the loop. It should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) //Displays number of occurrences for each         character A-Z
{
    cout << alphabet[i] << endl;
}
```

Pay attention to the code you are writing, since the compiler will do exactly what you tell it, even if it makes no sense.

Comment: Yes I am aware that my code is not working, clearly. What I am confused on is, how do I take a text file, convert to a string, loop through all 26 letters, and then display most frequent letter and the number of occurrences.

Comment: @Jordan Well with my corrections above your code should convert to uppercase and display all the occurances (but I've done no testing, there may still be errors). As for finding the most frequent letter, that's something I'll leave to you. It's not difficult, it's not technical, I'm sure you can work it out given what you have so far.